# link to extern php-file where the link also contains javascript which is executed on the linked website

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, hyperlink

I have a `page_x.php` which is nothing special. I also have a `page_y.php` with a form containing a dropdown field.

I want to place a link `<a href="page_y.php">link</a>` from `page_x.php` to `page_y.php` whose link will also select the third value of the dropdown.

How do I do this?

**Update:**

With regard to [mplungjan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748458/link-to-extern-php-file-where-the-link-also-contains-javascript-which-is-executed/2750536#2750536):

I will check that. Yes I can add code to the target-file.

I've also have been thinking about doing that with php `$_GET` and setting the default value.

I am surprised (am not very experienced in JS) that I could not add a JS/browserbased code which selects the `ElementById` for the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that only if you can insert a script on the page with the dropdown

```
<a href="pagey.html?2">Load and select the 3rd value</a>
```

pagey:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function() {
  var passed = location.search;
  if (passed) {
    var sel = parseInt(location.search.substring(1));
    document.getElementById('selectID').selectedIndex=sel;
  }
}
</script>
<select id="selectID">...
```